# Lubricating / taking care of plastic zipper

Tags: gear

How to lubricate / take care of a plastic zipper, so that it doesn't get stuck and have a longer life?

I know that for metal zippers, wax makes wonders, but what about plastic ones? Is the silicon spray appropriate, or there are better ones?

I'm asking especially about water-proof zippers, that are expensive to replace.

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Zipper Lubricant Stick made by GearAid](https://www.gearaid.com/products/zipper-lubricant-wax) to lube the plastic zipper on my drysuit. Works great to keep it moving freely. If you get sand or something in the zipper just use a clean soft toothbrush and then reapply the lube.

It is a soft-wax semi-solid base that they claim also helps protect the zipper against corrosion, UV damage, water, and extreme temperatures.

In response to your point about using silicone spray, it interestingly specifically advertises that it is silicone free. Although I couldn't tell you why silicone is bad, if it even is bad, for the zipper.

This brand is also [sold by Kokatat](https://kokatat.com/mcnett-ziptech-lube-acziplube), arguably the premier kayaking drysuit manufacturer, so you can view that as whatever level of endorsement of the product by them that you choose.

Comment: Interesting, I see a bunch of people (including some reputable outdoors sites) selling silicone zipper lubricants. Perhaps it is too slippery for drysuits and allows the zipper to come undone?

Comment: Thanks for the improvement - I certainly think that's better than previously.  I concur with your point about the manufacturer ceasing - but having at least the name might enable Web searches to find what equivalents are used, and it certainly helps anyone reading offline.

Answer (score 1):

My dry suit came with a tube of lubricant. I do not know what is in there, but this would be my way to go. It can easily be found by googling for it

Comment: It would be very much appreciated to know the name/brand of the lubricant, to make the googling easier.

Comment: Mine is from TIZIP.